# Check if directive evaluates to a particular HTML element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm using Yeoman to set up my AngularJS project. Trying to test a directive using Jasmine. This directive evaluates to a `ul` element. I'm testing to see if this is successful. How to write the syntax using Jasmine? I'm following the example that `Yo angular:directive` generates. I would also like to know if I'm approaching this in the right way? Any pointers to learn Jasmine properly?

In addition to the answer below, I managed to install and use jasmine-jquery to get my job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your directive, you can compile your HTML template in your jasmine tests:

```
describe('Unit testing great quotes', function() {
var $compile;
var $rootScope;

// Load the myApp module, which contains the directive
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

// Store references to $rootScope and $compile
// so they are available to all tests in this describe block
beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
  // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
  $compile = _$compile_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
    var element = $compile("<your-directive></your-directive>")($rootScope);

    // fire all the watches, so the scope expression {{1 + 1}} will be evaluated
    $rootScope.$digest();

    // Check that the compiled element contains the templated content
    expect(element.find("ul").length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
});
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

The tutorial on Jasmine home page is actually really good http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to use jQuery syntax by using jasmine-jquery. But you explained a couple of details here, which is very helpful.